# How to add a separate Java option per instance in GlassFish Cluster (Glassfish 4)?

Tags: glassfish, cluster-computing, instance, jmx, javaoptions

I have a cluster with 5 instances on Glassfish 4.
All are using the same configuration with the same Java options.
I want to add a Java option -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=**** for every instance in cluster, this means they all have to be different.
What is the best way to do that?

I can't move all instances to separate configurations,and I did not find any information about setting the parameters in instance system properties or instance properties.

Thank's for help!

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for separate instances in cluster is the following.
1) Add a JVM option for the cluster configuration:
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${jmxremote.port}
2) Add an instance option at node properties:
jmxremote.port with your preferred prot number. 
Save and restart instance.